# html/ts Button with pic and sound - the sound does not work, so what's wrong?

Tags: html, typescript, button, audio, pug

I currently work on a little website project. For this one I need buttons with pics and sound. Well, now I already work for a while on it, but the sound still does not work (except on one way completely in html....but I don't want that). It must work in Chrome and Firefox. I also need to look/want to now (still a beginner) how I can turn the sound on and off each time I press the button, but first, I want to hear sound at all...

So what can I do here?

I work in HTML/pug and ts (could only find js in code here, but well):

```js
function playMusicButton1(){
  let music = new Audio("/sound/revolution.mp3");
  music.loop = true;
  music.play();
}

playMusicButton1();
```

```html
button(onClick="playMusicButton1()")
  img(src="img/Music_Buttons_pixel_sun.png")
```

Answer (score 0):

### Run Snippet code!

**You can customize this code further as per your requirement.**

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
    <audio id="audioFile">
        <source src="https://rb.gy/v4em61" type="audio/mpeg">
        Your browser does not support the audio element.
      </audio>
      
      <p>Click the buttons to play or pause the audio.</p>
      
      <button onclick="playAudio()" type="button">Play Audio</button>
      <button onclick="pauseAudio()" type="button">Pause Audio</button>
      
      <script>
        var x = document.getElementById("audioFile");
        function playAudio() {
          x.play();
        }
        function pauseAudio() {
          x.pause();
        }
      </script>
  

</body>
</html>
```

---

### WANT TO SHOW AUDIO CONTROL

**just put ***controls*** in ***audio*** tag**

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
    <!--just add "controls" in audio tag-->
    <audio id="audioFile" controls>
        <source src="https://rb.gy/v4em61" type="audio/mpeg">
        Your browser does not support the audio element.
      </audio>
      
      <p>Click the buttons to play or pause the audio.</p>
      
      <button onclick="playAudio()" type="button">Play Audio</button>
      <button onclick="pauseAudio()" type="button">Pause Audio</button>
      
      <script>
        var x = document.getElementById("audioFile");
        function playAudio() {
          x.play();
        }
        function pauseAudio() {
          x.pause();
        }
      </script>
  

</body>
</html>
```